# Could Not Find the Main Class: HelloWorld. Program will Exit

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.jar file keeps giving me “ could not find the main class”. Program will exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875839/jar-file-keeps-giving-me-could-not-find-the-main-class-program-will-exit)

Trying to run a basic "hello World" program. I have followed step by step tutorials and i get the same error message each time:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Here is the Program:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Has anyone had this same issue and know how to resolve it?

Comment: How (or are) you setting your classpath?

Comment: what is the command you're using to run the program?

Answer (score 0):

Is the this is the tutorial you are following:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html  ?

If not, try to do that one and see if you get the same result.

Also, try to run your application as follows:

C:\java.exe yourjavaprogram.Main

Or you can google the error and you will probably find the solution faster than you think :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile the program? In command prompt type
    javac HelloWorld.java
This will make a .class file in the same folder. Now type
    java HelloWorld
should work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your java file is in a package which lives in a "source folder" in Eclipse parlance. That means the icon should look like an open folder containing an orange-ish square with a plus-shape superimposed on it, and the HelloWorld.java file should have a solid blue J on the document icon. If the folder icon just looks like a regular folder, and/or the java file has an outlined J on it, Eclipse won't even compile that code.