# jar file is not executing on double clicking on windows 7

Tags: java, windows, executable-jar

I have CQ5 executable jar file.It is suppose to be executed on double clicking.But i get error saying "could not find Main class program will exit".The same jar file executed on all my team mates machine but i am unable to execute it.

I am working on windows 7 OS.
I have jre6 installed.

I have done all steps provided in following link [.jar file keeps giving me " could not find the main class". Program will exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875839/jar-file-keeps-giving-me-could-not-find-the-main-class-program-will-exit).

my ftype and assoc is set to propervalue.
there is no problem in manifest file(becoz it executed on others machine).
all my path variables are set properly.

type of file on my system is "JAR" but on everyone else machine its "Executable JAR"
Could not figure out what is problem with my system.

Help plz.

Comment: Verify that the manifest file is correct in the JAR, and that the appropriate class is actually in the JAR...

Comment: Have you tried running it from the command line?  If it runs from the there it should def be the manifest, if it doesn't the .jar itself is likely the problem

Comment: actually jar is provided by adobe.we just have to execute it.I have not built this jar.It is executing on others machine not on mine

Comment: Sounds like your .jar association might be off,  have a look at something like this.  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/since-updating-to-windows-7-i-am-unable-to-run-any/b4b2c2fb-8634-4d26-bf76-a27cb7e6cbff  Hope it helps

Comment: i have done all things provided in the link "answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/" but still not working

Comment: Why not just create a small launcher for your jar? the easiest would be a [.bat file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811974/how-to-create-a-cmd-file-to-run-jars/18812097#18812097), If you want you can even create an `.exe` using a wrapper such as [jsmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/). In both cases you'll have a `native executable` for windows.

Answer (score -1):

You can alternatively try executing this command from a command console,
first CD to the location where you have the jar file and execute

For Win7 32-bit:

> java -Xmx1024M -jar .jar

For Win7 64-bit:

> java -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx1024M -jar .jar

if you have supported version of Java installed correctly, then the command should be able to start the CQ5 server. In that case, for fixing the double click issue, you would need to fix the filetype association of .jar files to open with /bin/javaw.exe

For supported Java versions, refer

CQ5.5 http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/deploying/technical_requirements.html

CQ5.6 http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/deploying/technical_requirements.html